# Selection of neighbors cells in a hexagonal field

Tags: sql, mysql, algorithm, hexagonal-tiles

Imagine hexagonal space with 3 dimensions.

Each tile has coordinates XYZ. 
I need to select a given cell neighbors in the same plane.
With SQL it's looks like:

```
$tbDir = $y % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1;

$result =  db_query('SELECT x,y,z FROM {cells} WHERE
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d OR
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d OR
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d OR
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d OR
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d OR
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d OR
                    x = %d AND y = %d AND z = %d ',
                    $x, $y, $z,
                    $x-1, $y, $z,
                    $x+1, $y, $z,
                    $x, $y-1, $z,
                    $x, $y+1, $z,
                    $x+$tbDir, $y-1, $z,
                    $x+$tbDir, $y+1, $z);
```

But, i don't like this way. 
Perhaps someone know more optimal algorithms?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you can use a between

```
x BETWEEN $x-1 AND $x+1 AND y BETWEEN $y-1 AND $y+1 AND z = $z
```

This might not exactly work for the $tbDir section. I will have a look at this case in more detail.

OK, rather try this

```
WHERE   x BETWEEN ($x-1 AND $x+1 AND y = $y AND z = $z)
OR      (y BETWEEN $y-1 AND $y+1 AND x = $x AND z = $z)
OR      (y BETWEEN $y-1 AND $y+1 AND x = $x + $tbDir AND z = $z)
```

or even

```
WHERE   (   (x BETWEEN $x-1 AND $x+1 AND y = $y )
            OR      (y BETWEEN $y-1 AND $y+1 AND x = $x)
            OR      (y BETWEEN $y-1 AND $y+1 AND x = $x + $tbDir)
        )
AND     z = $z
```

Comment: I almost didn't notice the $tbDir case before I commented.  This looks good to me.  It also allows for indexes to be placed on x, y, and z for a further optimization.

Comment: Here is result with 9 tiles, but needed 6 + target. extra 2

Comment: i think the last example is most optimal. Thank you!

Comment: Was an interesting problem X-)

Comment: This is only the beginning :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy mapping if your algorithms can work with a non-orthogonal coordinate system. In your case, the part of the hex tile which is parallel to an axis seems to be vertical:

```
 / \ / \ / \
| a | b | c |
 \ / \ / \ / \
  | d | e | f |
 / \ / \ / \ /
| x | g | h | i
```

If you can accept a skew Y axis, then you can give `a`, `d`, `g` the X coordinate 0 (i.e. the Y axis goes through the centers of these tiles). (`beh` would have X == 1, `cfi` has X == 2 and so on). `x` has the coordinate (-1,2). Now you can move like this:

```
e -> f: x+1,y
e -> d: x-1,y
e -> b: x,  y-1
e -> c: x+1,y-1
e -> g: x-1,y+1
e -> h: x,  y+1
```

As you can see, the movements are now completely independent of the y position.

Comment: Is the problem that I can't skew the Y axis. Field already formed and cells added to db. Anyway, thanks!